# XSL:Add sibling node while creating value thrugh recursion

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Input:

```
<root>
  <name>a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,</name>
  <value>1,,3,,5,,7,,,,11,<value>
</root>
```

The expected output

```
<root>
  <out>a:1|c:3|e:5|g:7|k:11</out>
  <e>5</e>
  <j/>
</root>
```

I was able to get expected 'out through recursion.
But I need to print two values among those separately like 'e' and 'j'.
while looping ,if the names are 'e' or 'j' ,these elements should be created.I was not able to to do that.

Recursion code

```
<xsl:template match="//root">
      <xsl:param name="columnName" select="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k"></xsl:param>

        <root>
           <out>
            <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="normalize-space(name)" />
                 <xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(value)" />
            </xsl:call-template>                    
          </out>
       </root>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="merge">
        <xsl:param name="name" />
        <xsl:param name="value" />
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="','" />  
           <xsl:variable name="currentValue"  select="substring-before($value, $separator)"/>
            <xsl:if test="$currentValue!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($name, $separator)" /><xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(substring-after($value, $separator))" />
                 <xsl:with-param name="name" select="normalize-space(substring-after($name, $separator))" />
            </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
```

How can I add two elements while looping for getting 'out'.?

Comment: You have tagged the question as [tag:xslt-2.0]? Do you use an XSLT 2 processor? Using `tokenize` you don't need a recursive template.

Comment: It supports partially.
Oracle's XML Developer's Kit (12c Release 1) only partially supports XSLT 2.0.
The XPath 2.0 functions fn:tokenize, fn:matches, and fn:replace are not supported.

Comment: Actually I think Oracle XDK supports very little of XSLT 2.0. In future please make it clear what version of XSLT you are using, otherwise it's very easy for people writing answers to waste your time and their own.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to change the "merge" template to output elements of the form `<a>1</a>` which you can store in a variable and manipulate to get the output you want.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="//root">
    <xsl:variable name="nodes">
      <xsl:call-template name="merge">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="normalize-space(name)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(value)" />
      </xsl:call-template>              
    </xsl:variable>
    <root>
      <out>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nodes/*[normalize-space()]/concat(name(), ':', .)" separator="|" />
        <!-- Alternate approach if above does not work
        <xsl:for-each select="$nodes/*[normalize-space()]">
          <xsl:if test="position() > 1">|</xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ':', .)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
        -->
      </out>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$nodes/e" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="$nodes/j" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="merge">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="','" />  
    <xsl:variable name="currentName" select="substring-before($name, $separator)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$currentName!=''">
      <xsl:element name="{$currentName}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($value, $separator)" />  
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:call-template name="merge">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(substring-after($value, $separator))" />
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="normalize-space(substring-after($name, $separator))" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwD/1

Answer (score 0):

When you come from procedural thinking, it's very natural to think in terms like "while I'm looping through the values, I'll calculate something else that I'm going to need later as a side effect". Generally with functional programming, it's better to think a different way. Calculate each thing you need in the output independently, don't try to calculate several things in a single pass of the input.

What you can do, however, is to precompute variables as functions of the input data if they are going to be useful more than once. So in XSLT 2.0 you could do

```
<xsl:variable name="names" select="tokenize(name, ',')"/>
<xsl:variable name="values" select="tokenize(value, ',')"/>
```

You can then write a function

```
<xsl:function name="f:value" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$values[index-of($names, $key)]"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and then you can do, for example:

```
<e><xsl:value-of select="f:value('e')"/></e>
<j><xsl:value-of select="f:value('j')"/></j>
```

If you can use XSLT 3.0 then the natural solution to all of this is to use maps. Like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="names" select="tokenize(name, ',')"/>
<xsl:variable name="map" as="map(*)"
  select="map:merge(
           for-each-pair($names, 
                         tokenize(value, ','),
                         function($k, $v) {map{$k, $v}}))"/>
</xsl:variable>
<out>
  <xsl:value-of select="$names ! (. || ':' || $map(.))" separator="|"/>
</out>
<e>{$map?e}</e>
<j>{$map?j}</j>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.Oracle's XML Developer's Kit (12c Release 1) only partially supports XSLT 2.0. The XPath 2.0 functions fn:tokenize, fn:matches, and fn:replace are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least XSLT 2 support, then you could use `tokenize` and transform your two sequences of values into some XML you can then process further:

```
<xsl:transform 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all" 
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="pairs">
              <xsl:variable name="values" select="tokenize(value, ',')"/>
              <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(name, ',')[. castable as xs:QName]">
                <xsl:element name="{.}">
                  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$values[$pos]"/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:variable>
          <out>
              <xsl:value-of select="$pairs/(* except (e, j))[normalize-space()]/concat(name(), ':', .)" separator="|"/>
          </out>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$pairs/(e, j)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/gWcDMez

With XSLT 3 you could even push the sequence of strings returned from `tokenize` to a template to construct the intermediary XML (although I have to admit I like the suggestion to use maps that Michael Kay has already posted more than this use of XML):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
      <xsl:param name="values"/>
      <xsl:element name="{.}">{ let $pos := position() return $values[$pos] }</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="pairs">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="tokenize(name, ',')[. castable as xs:QName]">
                  <xsl:with-param name="values" select="tokenize(value, ',')"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:variable>
          <out>
              <xsl:value-of select="$pairs/(* except (e, j))[normalize-space()]!(name() || ':' || .)" separator="|"/>
          </out>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$pairs/(e, j)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqz/1

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.Oracle's XML Developer's Kit (12c Release 1) only partially supports XSLT 2.0. The XPath 2.0 functions fn:tokenize, fn:matches, and fn:replace are not supported

Comment: @FayizTK, I am afraid that I don't know what at all Oracle's XML Developer Kit supports in terms of XSLT and XPath 2 so I can't make good suggestions on how to rewrite the above XSLT 2 suggestion for it. If you rewrite the use of `tokenize` to create the intermediary elements to use a recursive template instead then `<xsl:copy-of select="$pairs/(e, j)"/>` hopefully works if sequences are supported, otherwise you would need to use `<xsl:copy-of select="$pairs/*[self::e|self::j]"/>`.

Comment: No idea whether they support the `separator` attribute on `value-of`, if not, use a `for-each select="$pairs/(* except (e, j))[normalize-space()]"` and output `value-of select="concat(name(), ':', .)" inside.